# Socket Android with Java on WiFifreezing on sending file

Tags: java, android, file, sockets, programming-languages

i'm doing a server with Java and a client with Android. Everything works fine, but when i try to receive the file on Android, the IO input freezes. I tried to do the same with a Java test app, and works fine.

My code on the client side:

```
                int bytesRead;
                long current = 0;

                byte [] mybytearray = new byte[InfoPrograma.BUFFER_LENGTH];

                //Receive file
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file)
                );

                while (
                    (bytesRead = is.read(
                        mybytearray, 
                        0, 
                        mybytearray.length
                    )
                ) >= 0) {
                    current += bytesRead;
                    bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , bytesRead);
                }

                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
```

The server side code:

```
                    File file = new File(fileStr);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[InfoPrograma.BUFFER_LENGTH];

                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(file)
                    );

                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

                    long tmp = 0;

                    while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        tmp += count;

                        System.out.println(tmp);
                    }

                    os.flush();
```

BUFFER_LENGHT is 2000. If you need anything else, ask for it, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the socket ever close on the server side when it is done sending the file?  If the connection stays open, the read at the client may not be behaving as you expect.  Do you know if you are blocking on the read or spinning in the while() with a bytesRead of 0?

Comment: The socket on the server doesn't close. Even i removed the timeout setting. I looked again at it on a debuugging, and it seems to receive the file entirely, but when doing the last read, when there are no bytes to receive, it blocks. How can prevent it to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if closing the output stream will do it, but if not there is an explicit close() for socket.  Closing the socket on the server side should cause the client read to return 0.  You should change the read check on the client to loop while read is > 0 and interpret 0 to mean "socket closed, end of file."

Comment: Not exactly: when socket is closed, it will return -1, as i read on the documentation.

Comment: Ah yes, [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) returns -1 to indicate end of stream.  In traditional UNIX sockets recv() returned -1 on error and 0 on the other side performing an orderly shutdown [man recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it. The only way i found is to send first the lenght of the file to the client, save it, and then do read() while (on my code) current < fileLength.